# javascript modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used scrolling script from this site. http://blog.waiyanlin.net/example/jquery/flyingtext.html. I need the animation scrolls from right to left. How can i do that?

Comment: have you tried something? can you post code that you have tried

Comment: Solution on SO - [Duplicate][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042092/using-jquery-animate-to-animate-a-div-from-right-to-left

Comment: Here is the code.http://jsfiddle.net/cQuqJ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `marginLeft` with `marginRight` and edit the CSS so the text is right aligned.

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/DkRRw/

Comment: If i used image which is 900px width instead of the text the sliding doesn't works fine. How can i correct that?

Comment: I'm afraid that wasn't part of the original question. My feeling is you're very lazy and trying to get others to do all the leg work for you. Fire up Google and investigate CSS/Javascript, what you're trying to do isn't very difficult, even for a beginner. That way you'll actually learn something!

Comment: I have been working for three days to correct this issue. But i couldn't correct that.

Answer (score 0):

find-replace your code, change `Left` with `Right` inside your `document.ready()` js

Comment: I have used image instead of the scrolling text. The width of the image is 900px. Now it is not sliding fine as the text slides. How can i correct that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have seen this animation is done by animating the left-margin of text from 0 to some pixals.

What you want to do is to animate it from right hence you can **set marginRight**, in the script, insteed of marginLeft.

**UPDATE:** 
In css you will also have to use

```
.flying-text
{
    //Remove this: margin-left:-100px;
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

Comment: We have set marginRight instead of marginLeft. But the script doesn't works properly after the modification.

Answer (score 0):

As BondyThegreat pointed out, you need to swap Left with right in the script.  You also need to make a change to the style sheet.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.container .flying-text').css({opacity:0});
    $('.container .active-text').animate({opacity:1, marginRight: "350px"}, 4000);

    var int = setInterval(changeText, 5000);    


function changeText(){

    var $activeText = $(".container .active-text"); 

    var $nextText = $activeText.next(); 
    if($activeText.next().length == 0) $nextText = $('.container .flying-text:first');

    $activeText.animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
    $activeText.animate({marginRight: "-100px"});

    $nextText.css({opacity: 0}).addClass('active-text').animate({opacity:1, marginRight: "350px"}, 4000, function(){

        $activeText.removeClass('active-text');                                           
    });
}
});
</script>
```

Update the style sheet to:

```
.flying-text{
   margin-right:-100px;
   text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: I have used image instead of the scrolling text. The width of the image is 900px. Now it is not sliding fine as the text slides. How can i correct that?

Comment: @user1101208 - First you up vote all the posts that gave you a good answer to your problem, and select one to choose as the best answer.  Secondly, you post a new question with an updated jsFiddle that shows the problem.  Third, your problem gets solved.  We are all working for points here.