# jquery, animate image flying from right to left (loop)

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a img-tag (a bird) and I want to animate it from right to left with jQuery. it is supposed to fly in an out again and again.

quite like the little yellow helicopter flying through the sky on this website: http://www.abramsbooks.com/wesandersoncollection/

can somebody please help me?

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482499/jquery-to-animate-image-from-left-to-right-continously

And there is a working example :)

Comment: hmm, the spritely-thing? I've downloaded it, but I hardly know any jQuery and I don't know which parts of the plugin I need.. :(

Comment: No, read this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16485940/911718
And this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tTman/

Comment: but in the fiddle the cloud is not moving through the window like the helicopter in my example: http://www.abramsbooks.com/wesandersoncollection/

Answer (score 0):

First you get the width of your window, in this case im using the container div i just created, then you just need to loop it. Of course this is very simple but it should give u an idea.

```
var width = $('#container').width();

function loop() {
        $('#chopper').css({left:0});
    $("#chopper").animate({"left":width}, 5000, "linear", function(){
            loop();
     });
}
loop();
```

Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ap8n3/

Comment: thank you, that looks good! :) what can I do if the website is dynamic and I only use percentages?