# Animate object between relative "position:absolute" coordinence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a box that is in this position

```
position:absolute;
right:20px;
top:10px;
cursor:pointer;
```

When I click it I want it to be in this position

```
position:absolute;
right:unset;
left:500px;
top:10px;
cursor:pointer;
```

As seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/syogua8o/1/

That part is simple, the hard part is getting it to animate between those positions. I want the object to get an ease motion between those two points. I don't know how to go about doing this. Anything works as long as I can be 20px left and 500px right of the viewport edge when animating. I need it to be relative to the viewport edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `left` and `width` from after `css` has been calculated and add a css transition. Window resize won't be handled, but you can probably add a function that redoes the calculations.

```
$("box").css('left', $('box').position().left+'px')
$("box").css('width', $("box").width()+1)

$("box").click(function () {
    $("box").toggleClass("newpos");

});

box {
    position:absolute;
    background:red;
    right:20px;
    top:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition: left 2s ease-out;
}
box.newpos {
    right:unset;
    left:500px !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q8a1sjtx/1/

Answer (score 1):

I am using animate hear now as you can see i provided right 0px because if you provide 500px with position:absolute; then it will still at that position this is just an example of how to animate now you can provide left or any style you want in this animate function.

> Even you can Provide css also and then animate 
>   [using jQuery .animate to animate a div from right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042092/using-jquery-animate-to-animate-a-div-from-right-to-left)

**See above link for animation.**

Or you can use jquery ui also

For that see this link http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/oxL8vanw/

> **This all are reference for you how to animate using different pattern and as you can see Julien Grégoire given you css solution that is also nice**

---

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/syogua8o/3/

```
   $("box").click(function () {

    $("box").animate({
        right: "0px"
    },'slow');
});
```